# Split Flask view functions into two files

Tags: python, flask

I have a fairly large Flask application and I have encountered a need to create view functions in a separate python module. Right now I have all of my view functions in one module where I create my Flask app object, all my view functions, and run the Flask dev server. All of these views so far are urls that users will actually see when using the application so I am okay with keeping these in this existing module. However, I need to have an API where another application will be posting JSON to specific urls. I would like to keep these API handlers (views) separate from the other views.

I have already read the documentation here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/. The way I see it I have two options. I can put my application in a package and create the Flask app in the __init_.py, then import views from each file there as well, with a module to run the app next to the package like it is shown in the docs, or I can create a blueprint for my API handlers and register the blueprint in my existing module.

I am not sure what is the best way to go about this. I am leaning towards blueprints but I need feedback on what other people have done in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not generally a good question for Stack Overflow, since it appears you're asking for an opinion and your question is vague. You should post code that you've already tried and have a more specific question.

Since you're new, I'll answer as best I can, with the very limited information you posted.

I highly recommend using Blueprints for your situation. It will make it a lot easier in the future to manage the application if it's broken up into modules that are glued together with blueprints. Then you would have a small __ init__.py script, that primarily registers the blueprints.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I will try to post more specific questions in the future.